Compact mapping of differential operators
Suppose we have functions $F : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ that must satisfy some differential equation on $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$. Additional we write $\mathbb{R}^n$ as the typical spherical decomposition $\mathbb{S}^{n-1} \times \mathbb{R}^+$
Given a differential equation on $\mathbb{S}^{n-1} \times \mathbb{R}^+$, I want to find the corresponding equation on the compact domain $\mathbb{S}^{n-1} \times [0, 1]$, such that the range of the function is also compact.
In other words, if $L$ is a differential operator on $\mathbb{S}^{n-1} \times \mathbb{R}^+  \to \mathbb{R}$ and $\tilde{L}$ is the corresponding operator on $\mathbb{S}^{n-1} \times [0,1]  \to [0,1]$,  then I want to find $\tilde{L}$ such that $L(F)=0 \iff \tilde{L}(\tilde{F}) = 0$
I intend to achieve this by doing a transformation
$$ F(S^{n-1},r) \to \tilde{F}(S^{n-1}, \tilde{r}) $$
with
$$ \tilde{F} = \frac{2}{\pi} \tan^{-1}(F)$$
$$ \tilde{r} = \frac{2}{\pi} \tan^{-1}(r)$$
With the above mappings, this implies that
$$ \frac{\partial F}{\partial r} \propto d_{\tilde{F}}\tan(\frac{ \pi \tilde{F}}{2}) \frac{\partial \tilde{F}}{\partial \tilde{r}} d_r \tan^{-1}( r)  $$
$$ \frac{\partial F}{\partial r} \propto \frac{ \tan (\tilde{F})^2  + 1 }{ \tan (\tilde{r})^2 + 1} \frac{\partial \tilde{F}}{\partial \tilde{r}} $$
And a similar procedure for higher order derivatives
Question: Is $\tilde{L}$ obtained by replacing each derivative in $L$ with the corresponding derivative given as above? or there are other subtleties that I have to take care of?

I don't understand the question. "Given a differential equation on Sn−1×R+, I want to find the corresponding equation on the compact domain Sn−1×[0,1], such that the range of the function is also compact." I can't parse this sentence. Can you write it down more extensively? Additionally, making an example would help.
